# DateTime ParseExact gives System.FormatException:

Tags: c#, datetime, parsing, formatexception

I am getting the following error:

> System.FormatException: 'String '{ ActualInstallDate = 17/04/2020 09:06:23 }' was not recognised as a valid DateTime.

I have to add that in the database ActualInstallDate is nullable, that's why I'm converting it to string, to 'trick' it. The error comes at parsing actualInstallDates. Not sure what's wrong here.

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

```
var actualInstallDates = _context.Units.Where(u => u.ID == unitID)
                .Select(u => new {
                    u.ActualInstallDate
                }).Single().ToString();

            if (actualInstallDates != null)
            {

                DateTime actualInstallDate = DateTime.ParseExact(actualInstallDates, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                var nowString = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
                DateTime now = DateTime.ParseExact(nowString, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

                var averageWorkOver = (Math.Ceiling(Math.Ceiling(Convert.ToDecimal(now - actualInstallDate)) / 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) / workOverList.Count).ToString();
                ViewBag.AverageWorkOver = averageWorkOver;
            }
```

```
[Column(TypeName = "datetime2")] 
[Display(Name = "ActualInstallDate", Description = "ActualInstallDate_Description", ResourceType = typeof(Resource.Models.Unit))] 
public DateTime? ActualInstallDate { get; set; }
```

Comment: Well your date string is `17/04/2020 09:06:23` and your format is `dd/MM/yyyy` they don't match. Format is missing time.

Comment: Can you add `Units` class definition?

Comment: Is the code in the question producing this error? Note that you call ToString without a culture and ParseExact with, could that be the source of the problem? Also, why are you doing this at all? Converting a DateTime to a string, and then back? Why?

Comment: @jira I've tried "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss" as well and it wasn't working

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen because ActualInstallDate is DateTime? so to use it the (DateTime.Now - actualInstallDate) wasn't working because they are different types so i'm doing like that to basically convert it to a DateTime.

Comment: @Martas because there isn't only one. I have multiple units that have ActualInstallDate. If I don't specify that will it not give me multiple dates? I'm sorry that I am still learning this stuff. I appreciate your response, but honestly, an explanation of a better approach or why my method is failing is more meaningful. I don't think there is any point in saying "back to school".

Comment: @GuruStron the whole thing is very big, but this is for ActualInstallDate, which is in question at the moment: 
        [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
        [Display(Name = "ActualInstallDate", Description = "ActualInstallDate_Description", ResourceType = typeof(Resource.Models.Unit))]
        public DateTime? ActualInstallDate { get; set; }

Comment: `ParseExact` works as expected. You are trying to parse "'{ ActualInstallDate = 17/04/2020 09:06:23 " string. That is the stringified anon class you created in `Select`.

Comment: @RalucaMicu please see the update in my answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

- First of all you don't need to select it into anonymous object (if ActualInstallDate is string in database):

```
var actualInstallDates = _context.Units
    .Where(u => u.ID == unitID)
    .Select(u => u.ActualInstallDate)
    .SingleOrDefault();
if (actualInstallDates != null)
{...}
```

If you still want to, the don't call `ToString` on it:

```
var actualInstallDates = _context.Units.Where(u => u.ID == unitID)
    .Select(u => new { u.ActualInstallDate })
    .Single();
if (actualInstallDates.ActualInstallDate != null)
{
    DateTime.ParseExact(actualInstallDates.ActualInstallDate ...)
    ...
}
```

- Secondary your date format does not match with the string, try using

```
DateTime.ParseExact(actualInstallDates, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

**UPD**

Since your field is `DateTime?` it seems that you've been missing `Value` property on `Nullable<>` struct so you just need to fetch your date from db and use `actualInstallDates.Value`:

```
var actualInstallDates = _context.Units
    .Where(u => u.ID == unitID)
    .Select(u => u.ActualInstallDate)
    .Single()

if (actualInstallDates != null)
{
    var averageWorkOver = (Math.Ceiling(Math.Ceiling(Convert.ToDecimal(DateTime.Now - actualInstallDates.Value)) / 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) / workOverList.Count).ToString();
   ViewBag.AverageWorkOver = averageWorkOver;
}
```

Comment: Where and Single in one chain have no sense. Replace Where by Single.

Comment: @Martas 1) what about projection? Where should I put it? 2) For me it is matter of preference, I think code with separate `Where` clause is more readable.

Comment: 1) _context.Units.Single(u => u.ID == unitID).ActualInstallDate
2) Definitely not. lots of garbage to read, lots of garbage to maintain, after Where I expect more records, but it is already given, it will be one only, so unclarifying the meaning and complicating later understanding.
3) actualInstallDates? - the ? is there why? How could Single return NULL??!! Single fails with exception, if it doesn't find Single item.

Comment: 1) this will fetch whole record from db when only one value needed 2) you don't agree that readability is matter of preference, ok) 3) agreed, moved from OP's original code, with selection  to anonymous class this check is not needed, as for `Single` returning null if you change `SingleOrDefault` to `Single` in first one it will return null at least in [some cases](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9jTDYu)

Comment: 1) Maybe, but when there will be more records, it will return all of them and then fail on Single 2) It is, but what you show, has nothing to do with readability. 3) Too complicated. Simply Single never returns null. SingleOrDefault yes. But there is Single, therefore ? has no sense. 4) If you are beginner, heavy use of var everywhere when possible is the best way to hell. Why do you introduce anonymous type with one field?

Comment: 1) no, it should not. Check the generated SQL please. 3) I've added example when single returns null. 4.a) there are A LOT of successful projects which use a lot of `var`'s, including but not limited to opensource ones 4.b) the same question which I had, as you can see in my post =)

Comment: @GuruStron Thank you for your clarification! That makes sense. However, in the database is DateTime? format. That's why I am making it in string to put it after in a DateTime because otherwise (DateTime.Now - actualInstallDate) wouldn't work because they are of different types. Do you have any suggestions regarding this?

Comment: @RalucaMicu see my code, there is `DateTime.Now - actualInstallDates.Value` not `DateTime.Now - actualInstallDate`

Comment: @GuruStron Sorry, I saw it after. Now it gives me for averageWorkOver System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.TimeSpan' to type 'System.IConvertible'.'

Comment: @RalucaMicu cause difference between 2 dates is [`TimeSpan`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=netcore-3.1) and this is whole another question)))

Comment: @GuruStron that's ok, I figured it out. I changed the whole thing and now is working. Thank you so much for you help!  var averageWorkOver = (Math.Ceiling(Convert.ToDecimal( ( (DateTime.Now.Subtract(actualInstallDates.Value)).TotalDays )/ workOverList.Count))).ToString();

Comment: @RalucaMicu was glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

You did'nt specify time in the format string. You can either truncate the time part from the date string or add time to the format string.
something like this:

```
 DateTime actualInstallDate = DateTime.ParseExact(actualInstallDates, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```